# Safari Regex error "invalid regular expression invalid group specifier name"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, safari

i'm having a problem with Regex, this Regex works fine in other browsers but Safari doesn't, i get the error `"invalid regular expression invalid group specifier name"`
Please help me convert this Regex, i'm trying to get the phone number from the string

```
var str = '@' + str;
var obj =  str.match(/(?<=\D)(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09)[0-9\,\s.-]{8,11}/gm);
```

Comment: I got the same error, but I am confused with the code, I have just learned regex, can you help me convert the code so it works on safari?

Comment: Please try this `\D(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09)[0-9\,\s.-]{8,11}`